# $k \subset A \subset B$, $B\supset k$ f.g., $\text{codim}_k(A) < \infty$ $\Rightarrow$ $B \supset A$ f.g. module?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Does this hold?

Let $k \subset A \subset B$ where $k$ is a field and $A,B$ are commutative rings.

If $B$ is a finitely-generated ring over $k$ and $\dim_k(B/A) < \infty$ then $B$ is a finitely-generated $A$-module.

---

I *think* the above is used in a proof that I'm trying to understand.
But it's not carried out so I guess it must be really obvious.

Comment: What is $B/A$? How do you quotient out by a subring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If $B=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and $\dim_k(B/A)<\infty$ we get that $x_i$ is integral over $A$ for each $i$.

The powers of the element $\hat x_i\in B/A$ are linearly dependent over $k$, so there exists $N\ge 1$ and $a_1,\dots,a_N\in k$ such that $\hat x_i^N+a_1\hat x_i^{N-1}+\cdots+a_N=0$ in $B/A$, that is, there exists $a\in A$ such that $x_i^N+a_1x_i^{N-1}+\cdots+a_N-a=0$. This shows that $x_i$ is integral over $A$, so the extension $A\subset B$ is finitely generated and integral, and therefore it's finite.

Comment: Why is $A \subset B$ finitely generated?

Comment: @Haderlump In general, if one has rings $R \subset S \subset T$ and $T$ is finitely generated over $R$ then it is finitely generated over $S$: if you have a polynomial expression with coefficients in $R$ then that's also a polynomial expression with coefficients in $S$.

Comment: Ah yes, of course.. thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

I think this works. Take $b_1, \dots, b_n$ in $B$ such that their images in $B/A$ span that space over $k$. Then $\{1, b_1, \dots, b_n\}$ spans $B$ over $A$.